# タグシノニム database ← db を提案します

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在データベース関連のタグとして [db](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db) と [database](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) の両方が存在し、それぞれにいくつかの質問が付いているようですが、db と database が個別に存在する意義は薄いと思われるので、

master : database
synonym : db

とする方向での統合を提案します。
シノニム提案をしようと思ったら、該当タグでの回答スコアが5点以上必要ということで提案できませんでした。提案に問題がなければ権限をお持ちの方に委託したいと思います。

Comment: 数日待ってみましたが、とりあえず反対される方はいなさそうなので、どなたか権限をお持ちの方にお願いしたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[db](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db) から [database](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) へのマージとシノニム作成を行いました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/database/synonyms